# jQuery timer using with TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript1.4

I'm new with TypeScript so sorry for the beginner question.

I'm trying to create a new JQueryTimer in TypeScript and start it after a keypress. I'm using the DefinitelyTyped jQuery and jQuery.timer definitions.

My app.ts:

```
/// < reference path='references.ts'/>
module app {
   function addKeyToString(e) {
        $("body").timer(
            function () {
                console.log("This function just got called");
            }, 10000, true
            );
        document.getElementById("typingSpan").innerText += e.char;
    }    
    document.onkeypress = addKeyToString;
}
```

And my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>


    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery.timer.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
    WriteHere: <span id="typingSpan"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

When I'm trying to start this and press a key I receive runtime error (at the first line of my function) which says:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'timer'

Can someone tell me what is the solution to my problem? I checked the DefinitelyTyped example and based on that this should work. Here is the link: [Link](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.timer/jquery.timer-tests.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the documentation for the library, https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer

This gives the example usage:

```
var timer = $.timer(function() {
    alert('This message was sent by a timer.');
});
```

Tests for d.ts files are not necessarily going to be correct and shouldn't be used as reference documents. I don't know why this one appears to be wrong.

Comment: In that case the compiler says property 'timer' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.  If I add the timer: JQueryTimer part from jquery.timer.d.ts's JQuery interface definition (and also delete from there) to the JQueryStatic interface definition in the jquery.d.ts it solves the problem. I don't know if it is a proper way of using this timer or only a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the TypeScript test (not written by the library author) probably worked at the time it was created (in 2013), and breaking changes were made to TypeScript in the meantime.  (That's pure speculation on my part but the whole TypeScript / ECMAScript story is in a state of flux right now.)

Sometimes the easiest & most future-proof thing to do is to just let JavaScript be JavaScript, and put the code that's complaining in a JavaScript wrapper function.  Inside a .js file or within a `<script>` tag, do something *like* this

```
function createTimer() {
    var timer = $.timer(function () {
        timerCallback();
    });
    timer.set({ time: 1000, autostart: false });
    return timer;
}
```

Declare a `var timer` and `function timerCallback() { }` in your .ts file.  This will let you use the timer object in TypeScript, although it won't have Intellisense.

To initialize it, do something *like* this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    timer = createTimer();
    $(".start").click(function () {
        timer.play();
    });
});
```